# Where the deploy files goes for .NET Web Service running inside Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, web-services, deployment

When I use my browser to test my web service, it opens at http://localhost:4832/ -- where can I find its files physically on my drive?

### Update

I do not want to know where the files of my VS.NET solution are located but where I should put the files of the web service... the .asmx, .dll and other files that I will install for the real web service later.

### Update 2

The webservice need to call some external DLL when initializing to get plugin. This is why I need to know where those files are to go put manually the plugin dll...

Comment: You want to know where the files must be installed ?
[drive]\Inetpub\wwwroot ... how you setup this part depends on your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So when you launch a webservice out of VS - Cassini (the built in web server) runs those files directly out of the bin file of that project.

http://localhost:4832/ will point to the folder that your code is located in (as suggested by ALassek) and directly consume your asmx file.  That asmx file will run off of the dll that was compiled to the bin folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you select your solution, go to View -> Properties Window. The Path field will tell you where the files are located.

---

The assembly files are stored in the .Net temp folder during development, because they are recompiled every time you make a change. When you Publish the website, they are placed in the Bin folder.

Comment: hummm This is where the CODE is... not the executable...?

Comment: I don't know what executable you're referring to. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

LFSR answer was quite fine and I was ready to accept it BUT just to be sure I added the line

"Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location" in the code to show me the path of the executing assembly and it seem to have all DLL in a temporary folder:

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\57e0fe88\e8cbe653\assembly...

Comment: Yes, that is where the compiled files reside where "root" is from the name of your project or solution I belive and the rest is some random hexadecimal values for folder names aside from the assembly, shadow and a few others that may pop up so that the "57e0fe88" may not always be there.

Comment: THe problem is the webservice require to use plugin dll so I do need to know where the compiled dll are to test them.

Comment: The assembly is stored in the .Net temp folder during development. When you Publish the site, it will be located in Bin.